# $\frac{dy}{dx}$, $\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}$, is there $\frac{d^{1.5}y}{dx^{1.5}}$?

Tags: calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it meaningful to take the derivative of a function a non-integer number of times?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4587/is-it-meaningful-to-take-the-derivative-of-a-function-a-non-integer-number-of-ti)

So about derivative everyone knows we have the first derivative second derivative. Is there any notion of one and a half derivative?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you searching for [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus)?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198901/half-derivative-of-x2/199022#199022).